# How to add/remove class of child element on click of var ID?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an accordion I'm using for a FAQ page. When a particular question is clicked, the section arrow  needs to change from right to down. All others need to default back to right. What am I missing to get this to work?

```
            <dd id="1" class="accordion-navigation">
                <i class="fa fa-chevron-right"></i> <a class="faq-toggle" href="#faq1">How can I plan my Wedding at Mayan Resorts?</a>
                <div id="faq1" class="content">
                  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
                </div>
            </dd>

            <dd id="2" class="accordion-navigation">
                <i class="fa fa-chevron-right"></i> <a class="faq-toggle" href="#faq2">Do you offer a service to plan the event start to finish?</a>
                <div id="faq2" class="content">
                  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
                </div>
            </dd>



$('.accordion-navigation').click(function() {
        var id = $(this).attr('id');

                if ($(id).hasClass('active')) {
                        $(id).find('i').removeClass('fa-chevron-right');
                        $(id).find('i').addClass('fa-chevron-down');
                }
                else if (!($('.accordion-navigation').hasClass('active'))) {
                        $('.accordion-navigation').find('i').addClass('fa-chevron-right');
                        $('.accordion-navigation').find('i').removeClass('fa-chevron-down');
                }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do not know exactly why it doesn't work but I made up my own solution - CSS and JS combo

http://jsfiddle.net/95rzLepo/

```
$(document).on('click', '.faq-toggle' ,function (e) {
    if($(this).prev().hasClass('fa-chevron-down')) {
        $(this).prev().removeClass('fa-chevron-down');
        $(this).prev().addClass('fa-chevron-right');
    } else {
        $(this).parents('body').find('.fa.fa-chevron-down').each(function (e) {
            $(this).removeClass('fa-chevron-down');
            $(this).addClass('fa-chevron-right');
        });

        $(this).prev().removeClass('fa-chevron-right');
        $(this).prev().addClass('fa-chevron-down');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Use your instance of `this` and `toggleClass` and you should be able to do this in just a couple lines:

```
$('.accordion-navigation').click(function() { 
    //Remove from all
    $('.accordion-navigation i').removeClass("fa-chevron-down").addClass("fa-chevron-right");    

    //Add to current
    $("i", this).toggleClass("fa-chevron-right fa-chevron-down");
});
```

Comment: BTW: If there's more than one accordion `dl` on the page, he'll have to use `.closest('dd').siblings().find('i.fa')` or something similar to isolate it.

Comment: This add to current doesn't work. The fa-chevron-down doesn't exist on the page to toggle. It needs to replace the fa-chevon-right that is there.

Comment: Only one DL in this instance.

Comment: @ScottBlair-- If it doesnt exist, `toggle` will add it. I edited the selector, it should toggle the class on the `i` - my bad.

Comment: That's really close. Just need to toggle the arrow back to right if you click the same .accordion-navigation to close itself. Right now, it retains the down arrow.